# Keep right-floated element on the same line as block

Tags: css, css-float

I have two elements with unknown width, one floated to the left, one to the right. Between them i have a block expanded to fit the container width.

The layout i want to achieve is this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| [Left] [Expanded                  ] [Right] |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

But the right-floated element is cleared to the next line:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| [Left] [Expanded                          ] |
|                                     [Right] |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

It works fine if the elements are in this order in the HTML: *Left, Right, Expanded*.
But to be more semantic, i need this order: *Left, Expanded, Right*.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpL5A).

Is it possible? Even if wrappers are needed...

Comment: Put the right floated element before the other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `display: table`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/GpL5A/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="expandoooo">
    <span class="left">Left</span>
    <span class="expanded">Expanded</span>
    <span class="right">Right</span>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
.expandoooo {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: table;
}
.expandoooo > span {
    display: table-cell;
}

.left {
    color: red;
}
.expanded {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    color: blue;
}
```

A small downside of this technique is that the dying browser IE7 [does not support `display: table`](http://caniuse.com/css-table), though there is a [JavaScript fix](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/).

Comment: Cool! This works perfectly. Even better than floating! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're restricted to using floats, you need to ensure that both .left and .expanded are floated left. You may want to use max-width too to prevent pushing .right down.

```
.left, .expanded {
   float: left;
}
```